# Java GET redirected URL after HTTP Post exceute failed

Tags: android, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

Sir, I am going to implement the login module by httppost. The mechanism is that when I 
put http paramaters into httppost and execute with the url http://api.apc.com/u/authorize , 
api.apc.com/auth/authorized?u=3cdndskjsijdso9808  will be returned

u= 3cdndskjsijdso9808  is the user token after successful login .

There are thousands of header fields printed out but no header "Location" can be found
in android devices but PC browser can be found when it comes to the implementaation and testing.

Would you please tell is there any other methods to get the attribute and values of the http response headers ?

The below is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();        
String url =                 "https://api.hkgalden.com/u/authorize";

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader("X-GALAPI-KEY", "ecb954a155e6bbd9fe3fe166940feb102c80ae90");
httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpPost.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

Log.v("HTTP", "Header Added");

try {
    //add HTTP parameters
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("appid", "27"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", "mobile_id"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dname", "Galden+ mobile device"));
    Log.v("HTTP", "Parameters Added");

    //send HTTP request

    //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
/*
    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");

    url += ("?" + paramString);
*/
    //execute HTTP response
/*
    HttpGet get = new                 HttpGet (url);
    get.addHeader("X-GALAPI-KEY", "ecb954a155e6bbd9fe3fe166940feb102c80ae90");
    get.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    get.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");*/


    final     HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpParams, false);                    
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
    //HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(get);
    Log.v("HTTP", "Request Executed");
    //if execute success
    int respondCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    Log.d("HTTP Status Code" , String.valueOf(respondCode));
    if (respondCode== 404  || respondCode == 200){
        SystemUtils.toast(getApplication(), "Login Success!");
        // String temp = httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
        // String temp = httpResponse.getLastHeader("Location").getValue();
        // String temp = httpResponse.getHeaders();
        // Log.v("URL", temp);
        Header[] headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
            Log.v(header.getName(), header.getValue());
        }
        for(Header header : httpResponse.getHeaders("Location")) {
            System.out.println("Location from connect:" + header.getValue());
            SystemUtils.toast(getApplication(), "URL : " +  header.getValue());
        }

        String data = slurp(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent() , 1024);
        Log.v("url", data);
    }
    else SystemUtils.toast(getApplication(), "Login Fail! Error code: " + Integer.toString(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup the params when constructing your DefaultHttpClient so that it doesn't automatically follow redirects.

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpParams, false);
HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams).execute(httpPost);
```

This is mostly coming from my recollection, but I do seem to remember that HttpClient by default will follow redirects unless explicitly told not to.

**EDIT** The submitter did not follow my original instructions correctly so I have duplicated the submitted code with the recommended fix as well as clarification on where NOT to put it.

```
/*
 * THIS is the location and manner I suggested using the http params with 
 * the DefaultHttpClient. I would suggest you read my comments further 
 * down in your code.
 */
final     HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpParams, false);                    
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
String url = "https://api.hkgalden.com/u/authorize";

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader("X-GALAPI-KEY", "ecb954a155e6bbd9fe3fe166940feb102c80ae90");
httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpPost.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

Log.v("HTTP", "Header Added");

try {
    //add HTTP parameters
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("appid", "27"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", "mobile_id"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dname", "Galden+ mobile device"));
    Log.v("HTTP", "Parameters Added");

    //send HTTP request

    //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
/*
    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");
    url += ("?" + paramString);
*/
    //execute HTTP response
/*
    HttpGet get = new                 HttpGet (url);
    get.addHeader("X-GALAPI-KEY", "ecb954a155e6bbd9fe3fe166940feb102c80ae90");
    get.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    get.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
*/


    /*
     * I have commented the below declaration that I had give you to indicate 
     * where it was that you claimed you used it THEN claimed it didn't work.
     *
     * I also want to point out that my suggestion indicated originally to
     * take the httpParams object and pass it as a constructor argument to the
     * DefaultHttpClient.
     *
     */
    /*
    final     HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpParams, false);                    
    */
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
    //HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(get);
    Log.v("HTTP", "Request Executed");
    //if execute success
    int respondCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    Log.d("HTTP Status Code" , String.valueOf(respondCode));
    if (respondCode== 404  || respondCode == 200){
        SystemUtils.toast(getApplication(), "Login Success!");
        // String temp = httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
        // String temp = httpResponse.getLastHeader("Location").getValue();
        // String temp = httpResponse.getHeaders();
        // Log.v("URL", temp);
        Header[] headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
            Log.v(header.getName(), header.getValue());
        }
        for(Header header : httpResponse.getHeaders("Location")) {
            System.out.println("Location from connect:" + header.getValue());
            SystemUtils.toast(getApplication(), "URL : " +  header.getValue());
        }

        String data = slurp(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent() , 1024);
        Log.v("url", data);
    }
    else SystemUtils.toast(getApplication(), "Login Fail! Error code: " + Integer.toString(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: why the memory itself can  cache such redirect url and make header location invisible   ?

Comment: still failed it is because there has no redirect url with parameters get . What should i do now ?

Comment: It still faILS SINCE "location"  header does not exist after http post

Comment: 11-16 22:19:12.988: V/Connection(31241): keep-alive
11-16 22:19:12.988: V/Set-Cookie(31241): __cfduid=d62653256fbe8bbbcbf2bb52336d9a9171384611656677; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.hkgalden.com; HttpOnly
11-16 22:19:12.988: V/X-Powered-By(31241): PHP/5.5.4-1~dotdeb.1
11-16 22:19:12.988: V/Set-Cookie(31241): hkgapi_apigalden_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%2...
11-16 22:19:12.988: V/CF-RAY(31241): ce4d326343000c5

Comment: Your updated code does NOT make use of the suggestion I provided.

Comment: How should I use then ?

Comment: I have followed the methods and code you have edited , Dave.
But still no "location" header returning